# Ubuntu stop responding when a browser are loading a very large horizontal HTML page

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, browser

I'm using Ubuntu.

When a browser is loading an HTML page which has a very large horizontal table (a table with thousands of `<td>`) all the system freezes and stops responding: all the monitors freeze (without becoming darker) and all mouse/keyboard inputs do nothing.

I need to do `REISUB` to restart the PC.

If the table has fewer columns but thousands of rows, it works.

Why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: What do the logs say? Even after reboot, you might be able to get some information on what happened before. You could also check that the HTML is correct and you are not, for example, nesting the cells.

Comment: where I can find that log?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown) might help, though it is a bit old. You can try to run `journalctl -b -1 -n 20` to see the last 20 lines from the last reboot.

Comment: what browser are you rendering this in and is it upstream?

Comment: Firefox (upated) and yes, its upstream.